# Symbolic arithmetic in Erlang

Tags: parsing, erlang, symbolic-math

The following is an exercise in the O'Reilly Erlang book:

Build a collection of functions that manipulate arithmetical expressions. Start with an expression such as the following:

`(~((2*3)+(3*4)))`

which is fully bracketed and where you use a tilde (~) for unary minus.

First, write a parser for these, turning them into Erlang representations, such as the
following:

`{minus, {plus, {num, 2}, {num,3}}, {num, 4}}`

which represents `((2+3)-4) ...`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, how you do it depends on what kind of parser you want. The easiest way is probably to use something like [yecc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/yecc.html) or [neotoma](https://github.com/seancribbs/neotoma) to generate a parser for this language.

If you are trying to write a parser by hand, that's certainly possible. Here's how you might start writing one:

```
-module(parser).
-export([parse/1]).

%% parser:parse("((2+3)+4)") =:= {plus, {plus, {num, 2}, {num, 3}}, {num, 4}}.

parse(S) ->
    {[Expr], ""} = parse(S, expr, []),
    Expr.

-define(IS_DIGIT(C), (C >= $0 andalso C =< $9)).
-define(IS_SPACE(C),
        (C =:= $\s orelse C =:= $\t orelse C =:= $\r orelse C =:= $\n)).
is_space(C) ->
    ?IS_SPACE(C).
is_digit(C) ->
    ?IS_DIGIT(C).

skip_space(S) ->
    lists:dropwhile(fun is_space/1, S).

parse([$( | Rest], expr, []) ->
    {[Expr], Rest1} = parse(Rest, expr, []),
    [$) | Rest2] = skip_space(Rest1),
    parse(Rest2, op, [Expr]);
parse(S=[D | _], expr, []) when ?IS_DIGIT(D) ->
    {Ds, Rest1} = lists:splitwith(fun is_digit/1, S),
    parse(Rest1, op, [{num, list_to_integer(Ds)}]);
parse([$+ | Rest], op, [Left]) ->
    {[Right], Rest1} = parse(Rest, expr, []),
    {[{plus, Left, Right}], Rest1};
parse([C|Rest], State, Acc) when ?IS_SPACE(C) ->
    parse(skip_space(Rest), State, Acc);
parse(S, _State, Acc) ->
    {Acc, S}.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look on mine code for inspiration:
https://github.com/pichi/epexercises/blob/master/Exercise3-8/e38.erl It uses hand written lexer and parser. There is also compiler to stack machine code and stack machine simulator.